trying to run govee desktop setup .exe file
https://desktop.govee.com/desktop/devices
I am trying to run Govee desktop setup it uses a .exe file, I have the most updated wine version. I did try to run it with wine it did not work.  The file is GoveeSetup.exe

That is a Windows file. Can not just run it on Ubuntu.

Not everything works on wine. You can use a Windows virtual machine (you can get a free trial of Windows for free) if you must use WIndows apps

The hard-working Wine developers do not have access to the Windows source code, so cannot duplicate all Windows syscalls. Therefore, Wine does not claim 100% compatibility for all Windows applications.
If your Windows application does not work under Wine, please ask the developer of that application to make their software compatible with Wine.
If that Windows application is Open Source, consider diving into the code yourself.
